# Generating sites from a single app all accesible with different domains

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, subdomain, multisite

I need to create an application through which I can generate different sites. All these sites will have the same layout but each one will have different contents (texts, images, colors, etc).

The hard part is that these sites should be able to be accessed through different urls.

Let me give an example:

I log into the application from there I create a new site with the name FooBar and it may be accessed through the http://foobar.com url.

The same if I want a site http://foobaz.com. All sites may be generated and managed from the same administrator.

I have read about Wordpress multisite and I think maybe it could help me. If its not possible via Wordpress I can make it with some web framework like Laravel.

The main problem I cant figure out is how to map the domains with each site generated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right way to do this is to point all the domains to the same laravel app+routes so then in the controllers you can do the check of the domain the user is currently visiting and get the images and texts accordingly the domain from the DB.

In other words, make the logics on the controllers/helper level.